# Printing RTF as part of existing print job

Tags: vb.net, printing, rtf, printdocument

I have an application that uses PrintDocument to print an Invoice, and I want to print some terms and conditions type fine print on 1 portion of the invoice after all of the items, customer info, and such. I am using a richtextbox for this text since I want my user to be able to format the fine print however they wish.

However, I can't print the rtf as I do all my other text, since it just prints the rtf formatting mumbo jumbo instead of the formatted text. I am seeing examples of how to print RTF that involves printing an entire document from a file such as:

```
PrintDialog1.Document = rtfTextBox.rtf
```

, but how do I just print a portion of a page with RTF text? Is this even possible? I can't find any examples of doing this anywhere.

Maybe not necessary but here is a visual: The only RTF text is the fine print, everything else on the page will not be.

```
_____________________________________
|            INVOICE          page 1 |
|   Customer:                        |
|   John Doe                         |
|   123 Main St                      |
|                                    |
| Items:                             |
| 1. Doodad          1 @ $5.95       |
| 2. Widget          3 @ 1.00        |
| 3  Gizmo           1 @ 34.32       |
|                                    |
|  Returns must be made in 30 days   |
|  with original receipt. Must be in |
|  original condition.               |
|                                    |
|  Customer Sig: __________________  |
|____________________________________|
```

Note: If this isn't possible, is it possible to attach an RTF page to the end of an existing print job? Or can RTF only be printed all on its own as a standalone print job, not mixed with anything else?

Comment: What if you get your RichTextBox content, append your terms and conditions, save it to a temporary .rtf file (for instance using `IO.File.WriteAllText`), print it as a whole document and then delete the file? Would it suit your needs?

Comment: Well, the rest of the invoice is printed like this:  g.DrawString("Item 1: " & itemText, New Font("Verdana", 12),Brush, 50, 100)... There is probably 50 things printed onto the invoice in different locations like this. It seems like 2 totally different ways of printing so i am not sure if they are compatible with one another...